# Add low frequency amplitude modulation to noise

Tags: chuck

I am trying to reproduce a SoX script using ChucK which creates brown noise with a slight oscillation (tremolo).

The [SoX script](https://web.archive.org/web/20190819134154/https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rsvp/1209835/raw/161f112588f66865c41ecdb9d26f7f19d852533f/noise.sh) is:

```sh
set -u
set -e

minutes=${1:-'59'}
repeats=$(( minutes - 1 ))
center=${2:-'1786'}

wave=${3:-'0.0333333'}

noise='brown'

len='01:00'

if [ $minutes -eq 1 ] ; then
     progress='--show-progress'
else
     progress='--no-show-progress'
fi

echo " ::  Please stand-by... sox will 'play' $noise noise for $minutes minute(s)."

play $progress  -c 2  --null  -t alsa  synth  $len  ${noise}noise  \
     band -n $center 499               \
     tremolo $wave    43   reverb 19   \
     bass -11              treble -1   \
     vol     14dB                      \
     repeat  $repeats

exit 0
```

The following ChucK script, modified from the [wind2.ck](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/examples/basic/wind2.ck) example, creates brown noise of the desired frequency:

```
Noise n => BiQuad f => dac;
0.99 => f.prad;
0.0333333 => f.gain;
1    => f.eqzs;
0.00 => float t;
while(true)
    5::ms => now;
```

I am unable to reproduce the effect that the SoX tremolo option creates.

It seems like I should be able to add a Sine wave to the main chain and then  oscillate that parameter.  I am trying variations of [FM.ck](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/examples/basic/fm3.ck) frequency modulation example without success:

```
SinOsc m => Noise n => BiQuad f => dac;
20 => m.freq;
200 => m.gain;
0.99 => f.prad;
0.0333333 => f.gain;
1    => f.eqzs;
0.00 => float t;
while(true)
    30 + ( Math.sin(t) + 1.0 ) * 10000.0 => m.sfreq;
    t + .004 => t;

    5::ms => now;
```

I expect to hear *some* fluctuation in the tone, but instead, no sound appears to be produced.

How can I add a low frequency amplitude modulation to the brown noise I've generated?

Comment: To have a tremolo effect, you need to modulate the amplitude of the sound, i.e. the gain of the noise.  Don't mess with the frequency.